# Tiers tree print all suffixed provied wrong output

Tags: c, algorithm, trie

I need to print all suffixes of a tires tree. I am using following traverse method to print all suffixes.

```
struct TrieNode {
    struct TrieNode *children[ALPHABET_SIZE];
    char label;
    bool isLeaf;
};

void traverse(char prefix[], struct TrieNode *root) {
    concatenate_string(prefix, &(root->label));
    if (root->isLeaf) {
        printf("%s\n", prefix);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        if (root->children[i]) {
            traverse(prefix, root->children[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Consider following Trie tree

```
    Root
 |     |    |
 L     M    N
|  |
a  b
```

So my expected output is

```
La
Lb
M
N
```

But my code prints

```
  La
  Lab
  LabM
  LabMN
```

As per my understanding root cause for the issue is not updating prefix variable correctly. How to fix this issue?

Comment: I think `prefix` needs to be reset or use copy.

Comment: Yes, i feel like use a copy will be fine. How can i do it?

Comment: Paul Ogilvie makes already suggestion to make a copy.  In order to reset, memorize the end of `prefix` and tell to `concatenate_string` the place of join.

Comment: such as `void traverse(char prefix[], struct TrieNode *root, int depth) {
  prefix[depth] = root->label; prefix[depth+1] = 0;`...`traverse(prefix, root->children[i], depth+1);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you keep concatenating. It is better to have `char prefix[]` as a local variable, e.g:

```
void traverse(char prefix[], struct TrieNode *root)
{
    char newprefix[30];
    strcpy(newprefix, prefix);
    concatenate_string(newprefix, &(root->label));
    if (root->isLeaf) {
        printf("%s\n",newprefix);
    }

    for(int i=0 ; i< 26 ; i++){
        if(root->children[i]){
            traverse(newprefix, root->children[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

and call like:

```
traverse("", root);
```

Comment: If we use it as a local variable, how to pass it recursively